# How to get generic list intance's specific item

Tags: java, list, generics

I don't know how to get a specific item for a generic list instance. Suppose I have something like this;

```
public class Column {

private String name;
private float width;

public Column(String name, float width) {
  this.name=name;
  this.width=width;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

and another class;

```
public class WriteColumn {

private List<Column> col = new ArrayList<>();

public void addColumn() {
    col.add(new Column("yo", 0.1f));
    col.add(new Column("mo", 0.3f));
    writeColumn(col);

public void writeColumn(List<Column> col) {
    String str = "";
    for (Column col1 : col) {
        str += col1 + " - ";
    }
    System.out.println("Cols: " + str);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    WriteColumn wc = new WriteColumn();
    wc.addColumn();
}
}
```

The output I want to get is the text part of the column but I am not getting it. Is there a simple way of doing it ?

Comment: `col1.getName()` is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot get why you cannot use getName() method?

It should work:

```
public void writeColumn(List<Column> col) {
  String str = "";
  for (Column col1 : col) {
    str += col1.getName() + " - "; 
  }
  System.out.println("Cols: " + str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working , Output :
Cols: yo - mo -

I guess this is what you are expecting.

```
package com.vipin.test;

import java.util.*;

class Column {

    private String name;
    private float width;

    public Column(String name, float width) {
        this.name=name;
        this.width=width;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class WriteColumn {

    private List<Column> col = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addColumn() {
        col.add(new Column("yo", 0.1f));
        col.add(new Column("mo", 0.3f));
        writeColumn(col);
    }
    public void writeColumn(List<Column> col) {
        String str = "";
        for (Column col1 : col) {
            str += col1.getName() + " - "; //used getName()
        }
        System.out.println("Cols: " + str);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WriteColumn wc = new WriteColumn();
        wc.addColumn();
    }
}
```